# In R, how can I add variables from different data frame

Tags: r, variables, addition

There are two tables (data frames) as below.

And, I want to add 'Cost' variable in DF1 based on the two conditions 'Departure' and 'Arrival'.  And the cost will be looked up in DF2.

I searched packages but could not find appropriate one.

If you have any idea for this, it will be appreciated.

```
DF1
ID    Departure    Arrival
01    LA           Chicago
02    NY           Denver
03    NY           LA
04    FL           Hawaii

DF2
Departure    Arrival    Cost
NY           Chicago    100
NY           Denver     200
NY           LA         300
NY           Hawaii     400
FL           Chicago    100
FL           Denver     200
FL           LA         300
FL           Hawaii     400
LA           Chicago    100
LA           Denver     200
LA           NY         300
LA           Hawaii     400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a job for `merge()` in the base package.

```
merge(DF1, DF2, by=c("Departure", "Arrival"), all.x=T, all.y=F)
```

This is merging the data frames based on the values in `Departure` and `Arrival`, keeping all records in `DF1`, and only corresponding records from `DF2`.

Comment: Hey, it worked.  Thanks.  But the corresponded records in DF1 from DF2 showed as NA.  Since there is no way it cannot be matched, this does not make sense.  Do you have any idea for this came up?

Comment: @DavidKo: If there is no matching record in `DF2`, it's expected that the value will be `NA`. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: "Since there is no way it cannot be matched" - I'm guessing your assumption is incorrect, which is why you're getting NAs

Comment: @thelatemail: Very true regarding `merge()`. I like to air on the side of explicit when merging though, just in case. :)

Comment: @AlexA.  Yes, my assumption should be incorrect.  I will try again.  Thanks. :)

Comment: @thelatemail  Thanks :)  I will try it again.  I am sure my assumption is incorrect.

Comment: @AlexA.Sorry for my late response.  Thank you again.  It helped alot. :)